# Customize history change trigger to skip hashchanges on same page in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, pushstate

I have a website with Barba.js to use pushState API to load pages. So to track these virtual page loads in GTM I added a History Change trigger to fire analysis page view event. It works great. 
But if I have on page anchors, e.g

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

This also fires the History Change event, and cause google analytics to record another page view which I don't want.

Is there a way to make a history change trigger that only fires on new pages e.g if `/services` changes to `/about` , and doesn't fire when URL changes from `/about` to `/about/#about`

**Update :** 
I have now used 'History Source' variable equals to 'pushState' condition to filter history change events because the hash change events is showing 'popState' in the History Source in the Data Layer variables. I am not 100% confident that this is correct, but it seems to be working.